# Adding items to List<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I was trying to add items to IList through reflection, but while calling the "Add" method an error was thrown  "object ref. not set". While debugging I came to know that the GetMethod("Add") was returning a NULL reference.

```
Type objTyp = typeof(MyObject); //HardCoded TypeName for demo purpose
var IListRef = typeof (List<>);
Type[] IListParam = {objTyp};          
object Result = IListRef.MakeGenericType(IListParam);

MyObject objTemp = new MyObject(); 
Result.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(Result, new[] {objTemp });
```

Please help.

Comment: I've worked quite a bit with reflection a while ago, and I came to the conclusion that I don't like the overload of `GetMethod(string)`, because I never knew if it would return. Try rather using `GetMethod(string, Type[])` or `GetMethod(string, BindingFlags)`. Might not make it work, and might just be me beeing paranoid, but I remember having a lot of confusion over similar problems before.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're trying to find an `Add` method in `Type`, not in `List<MyObject>` - and then you're trying to invoke it on a `Type`.

[`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) returns a type, not an instance of that type. If you want to create an instance, `Activator.CreateInstance` is usually the way to go. Try this:

```
Type objTyp = typeof(MyObject); //HardCoded TypeName for demo purpose
var IListRef = typeof (List<>);
Type[] IListParam = {objTyp};          
object Result = Activator.CreateInstance(IListRef.MakeGenericType(IListParam));

MyObject objTemp = new MyObject(); 
Result.GetType().GetMethod("Add").Invoke(Result, new[] {objTemp });
```

(I would also suggest that you start following conventions for variable names, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: Thank you very much, now its working. I missed out calling the "Activator.CreateInstance".

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks.  MakeGenericType just saved me loads of work.

Answer (score 5):

```
    private static void Test()
    {
        IList<Guid> list = CreateList<Guid>();
        Guid objTemp = Guid.NewGuid();
        list.Add(objTemp);
    }

    private static List<TItem> CreateList<TItem>()
    {
        Type listType = GetGenericListType<TItem>();
        List<TItem> list = (List<TItem>)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
        return list;
    }

    private static Type GetGenericListType<TItem>()
    {
        Type objTyp = typeof(TItem);
        var defaultListType = typeof(List<>);
        Type[] itemTypes = { objTyp };
        Type listType = defaultListType.MakeGenericType(itemTypes);
        return listType;
    }
```

IList.Add(object item); => you can use Add method in IList interface instead of Reflection.

Comment: Doesn't work. `IList Result = (IList)IListRef.MakeGenericType(IListParam);` throws `InvalidCastException Unable to cast object of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'System.Collections.IList'. `

Comment: Yes, you are right Alex, thanks your warning. I missed that I forgot create instance. And I edit code, and in this time, It is tested and it is working ;)))

Answer (score 0):

You have only created a generic type, you haven't created an instance of the type. You have a list type, but you don't have a list.

The `Result` variabled contains a `Type` object, so `Result.Gettype()` returns the same as `typeof(Type)`. You are trying to find an `Add` method in the `Type` class, not your list class.

Could you not use generics instead of reflection, e.g.:

```
public static List<T> CreateListAndAddEmpty<T>() where T : new() {
  List<T> list = new List<T>();
  list.Add(new T());
  return list;
}
```

Comment: The Generics based solution which you had suggested was an apt one. The reason why I didn't go for generics was that, the PropertyInfo.SetValue method wasn't accepting generic parameter references else I would have definitely went for the Generics version.