# Adding list<t> property using reflection

Tags: c#

I am reading a file which is like

HDR …

LIN …

LIN …

LIN …

HDR …

LIN …

LIN …

Now LIN corresponds to line items and belong to the HDR line above it.

Also, mapping for the data comes from xml which has already been deserilized. This has the mappings like which property to store the data in Header or LineItems class, how many chars to pick, if it is required or not etc.

The header model to store data looks like

```
public class Header
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Item> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use a generic function to load data before processing it.

I need help with

- (#1) in the below function: is it correct way to make sure that property LineItems is not null before adding the LineItem to it?
- How to do (#2) in below function, using reflection to add lineItem to `data[headindex-1].LineItems.Add(lineItem)`?

Here is the function...

```
public static List<H> ReadFile<H, I>(ConfigTypeUploadXml uploadConfig, string fileNamePath, ref string errMsg) where H : new() where I : new()
{
    // we'll use reflections to add LineItems to data
    var properties = typeof(H).GetProperties();

    // read the file line by line and add to data. 
    var data = new List<H>();
    var headIndex = 0;
    var lineIndex = 1;

    foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(fileNamePath))
    {

        // read HDR line
        if (line.StartsWith("HDR"))
        {
            var header = ReadHeaderLine<H>(uploadConfig, line, errMsg);
            data.Add(header);
            headIndex += 1;
        }

        // read LIN line
        if (line.StartsWith("LIN"))
        {
            var lineItem = ReadItemLine<I>(uploadConfig, line, errMsg);

            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                if (p.Name != "LineItems")
                    continue;

                //1) if items is null then create the object
                object items = p.GetValue(data[headIndex - 1], null);
                if (items == null)
                    p.SetValue(data[headIndex - 1], new List<I>());

                //2) add line item to data[headIndex - 1].LineItems.Add(lineItem)

            }
        }
        lineIndex += 1;
    }
    return data;
}
```

This article [Adding items to List<T> using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4194033/adding-items-to-listt-using-reflection) shows how to do it but this in on main object. In my case i need to populate `data[index].LineItems.Add(...)`

Comment: Why are we using reflection again?

Comment: @TheGeneral is there a better way to handle LineItems without reflection?

Comment: @TheGeneral plz don't delete your answer. It will be helpful for any one who doesn't have to rely on reflections. I would suggest to put it back for others to take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this via reflection, it's relatively easy.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;


var lineItem = ...;
var header = data[data.Count - 1];

var lineItemsProperty = header.GetType().GetProperty("LineItems");
var lineItems = lineItemsProperty.GetValue(header) as IList;
lineItems.Add(lineItem);
```

This takes advantage of the fact that [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) implements the [`IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) interface. When you call `IList.Add()`, the value is cast to the correct type and then passed to `List<T>.Add()`.

Comment: How did i miss this? Your other solution is something i'll put on the back burner. For now will go with this solution. Thanks

Comment: `lineItems.add(lineItem)` is resulting in `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`  since lineitems is null. When i do `if(lineItems == null) lineItems = new List<I>();`, the error goes away, .Add is successful in this case but when i look at the `data`, LineItems is null.

Comment: The missing piece was `lineItemsProperty.SetValue(header, lineItems)`

Comment: The other option is that your `ReadHeaderLine` function could set the `LineItems` property before returning. Given that `ReadHeaderLine` appears to be a factory function, it would make sense for it to fill in the `LineItems` class member.

Answer (score 1):

Does this need to be done via reflection? You could create a simple interface that all of the `Header`-like classes implement, e.g.

```
interface IHaveLineItems
{
    void AddLineItem(object item);
}
```

This can then be implemented on the various `Header` classes, e.g.

```
public class Header : IHaveLineItems
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Item> LineItems { get; set; }

    void IHaveLineItems.AddLineItem(object item)
    {
        LineItems.Add((Item)item);
    }
}
```

Your loop could then become:

```
var data = new List<H>();
IHaveLineItems lastHeader = null;
var lineIndex = 1;

foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(fileNamePath))
{
    // read HDR line
    if (line.StartsWith("HDR"))
    {
        var header = ReadHeaderLine<H>(uploadConfig, line, errMsg);
        data.Add(header);
        lastHeader = header;
    }

    // read LIN line
    if (line.StartsWith("LIN"))
    {
        var lineItem = ReadItemLine<I>(uploadConfig, line, errMsg);
        lastHeader.AddLineItem(lineItem);
    }

    lineIndex += 1;
}
```